# sed command edit multi files ( insert , replace line)

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Ive 30 files named ( db01.php up to db30.php  )

include this line

```
     require_once('config.php');
```

I want to add  or replace it to be

```
    require_once('../new/config.php');
```

how to use sed to edit these 30 files at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/\(require_once(.\)\(config\.php.);\)/\1..\/new\/\2/' db*.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/\(require_once('\)\(.*\.php\)\(');\)/\1..\/new\/\2\3/" db*.txt
```